# How to use 'InstrumentationTestRunner' to manager android library testcase with gradle

Tags: android, testing

I have an android project like this:

```
ProjectA
----app
--------src
------------androidTest
------------main
----libA
--------src
------------androidTest
------------main
----libB
--------src
------------androidTest
------------main
```

Can I manager all TestCase (app and lib) with one InstrumentationTestRunner？

I'm using `'./gradlew clean connectionAndroidTest'` to build project.

Answer (score 0):

InstrumentationTestRunner is deprecated by Google. 
Use AndroidJUnitRunner instead.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, but how do I solve the current problem